# Radial Menu Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, radial

How to create side radial menu in flutter like a picture any help would be appreciated.[image]

[image]

i also tried [this](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_menu) package but i got the following result not much accurate.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [**`circular_menu`**](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_menu) or [**`fab_circular_menu`**](https://pub.dev/packages/fab_circular_menu),use [**`animated_radial_menu`**](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_radial_menu) refer [**`this`**](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/animated-circular-menu-in-flutter-1c389b9011b3) artical also

hope its helpful to you

**Using Circuler Menu Package:**

```
 Container(
        height: 250,
        width: 150,
        child: CircularMenu(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          items: [
            CircularMenuItem(
              icon: Icons.home,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            CircularMenuItem(
              icon: Icons.search,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            CircularMenuItem(
              icon: Icons.settings,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            CircularMenuItem(
              icon: Icons.star,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Your Menu Icon Result-> [image]

Your Circueer menu Result-> [image]

Comment: I tried these packages as well but did not get accurate result

Comment: @KamranAli, check my updated answer and try to use `animated_radial_menu`  package

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: your problem is solved or not? and which package you used?

Comment: I used circular_menu package and as mentioned in question didn't get the accurate result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244319/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-kamran-ali).

Comment: @KamranAli check my updated answer

Comment: as i told you before I also tried this and did some modification on that as well but I want to get the same result as in image